# How to display the cell id of an html table , that is being selected?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code to create table with php by looping. I add an onclick function in each . So that on clicking a particular cell the background color is changed. How can I get the cell id number be displayed for each click.

```
<html>        
    <head>        
    <script>
    function changeColor(elem)
    {     
    elem.style.background = "red";     
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $rows = 10; // define number of rows
    $cols = 4;// define number of columns

    echo "<table border='1'>";

    for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

        echo "<tr>";
            for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
                   echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor(this)\" > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    ?>        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There are many libraries like jquery, ext2, prototypes that make a lot of this much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified any ids here
If you want to get the cell and row number Try this:

```
changeColor(elem){
  elem.style.background = "red";
 alert("Row Index is:"+elem.parentNode.rowIndex);
 alert("Cell Index is:"+elem.cellIndex);
}
```

Comment: i want to place an image or a css style icon in the cell of the grid that is being selected..how can i do that with js ??

Comment: elem.innerHTML = "Hello World" + elem.innerHTML; to append before and  elem.innerHTML += elem.innerHTML +  "Hello World"; to append after you can set any value instead of Hello World

Answer (score 0):

chnage this line

```
   echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor(this.id )\" id=".$tr."-".$td." > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
   <script>
function changeColor(id)
{     
$("#"+id).css('background-color', 'red');
}
</script>
```